# Why is this code ' partically covered' with VS 2012 code coverage?

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2012, code-coverage, code-analysis

I have this method, that is all covered by unit tests...except for one line, see sample.
The line is being executed which I can verify by debugging and the unit test.

```
decimal? balance = null;
//other code
else
{
   MyClass classBalance = _repository.GetMyClass();
   if (classBalance != null)
   {
        balance = classBalance.Dr- classBalance.Cr; //This line is yellow/partially covered, the rest is all covered.
   }
 }
```

Comment: Are you testing cases where `Dr` or `Cr` are null, as well as cases where they're non-null? All the possible mixtures?

Comment: I only have a test where both are filled with a value.

Comment: I added to tests, 1 for if Cr is null, 1 for if Dr is null, and that fixed it :) thx

Answer (score 0):

As @Jon Skeet suggested:

I added two tests, 1 for if Cr is null, 1 for if Dr is null, and that fixed it